# How to place an OTR microwave next to a wall

Tags: kitchens, microwave-oven

I am trying to replace an over the range (OTR) microwave since the previous (quite old) one stopped working. While the space is the standard 30" wide, to the left of the opening is essentially a wall, and while I tried to put in a couple of replacements, both of the doors failed to open fully because they hit the wall.

Sadly moving the cabinets is not an option, and the best I can come up with is trying to plane off the 1/4" lip on the cabinet and move the microwave over in the hope that gives enough room for the door to open.

A nicer option would be a door that has a hinge that is inset but I haven't been able to find anything so far beyond a low profile option that just feels too short.

Per one of the answers below, I had taken a look at Left-to-Right opening doors, but unfortunately couldn't find any either.  The best so far has been a low profile option from [Whirlpool](https://www.whirlpool.com/kitchen/cooking/microwaves/over-the-range/p.1.1-cu.-ft.-low-profile-microwave-hood-combination.wml35011kb.html?region_id=LDC822&cmp=whp:wp_mda%7c01%7c00412%7czz%7csh%7ct02%7cp10%7czz%7cv02_whp_ppc:ga:ps:txt:txt:cpc:shop_smartshop_test:na:na:12991343671:120661454134:c&gclid=CjwKCAjw2bmLBhBREiwAZ6ugo9z5a7OHVcLtmUBmoS_IXsd074-gtiV5AdFk6LciTrWWp4SFJB9qlBoC_bMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

This is the replacement microwave that doesn't open
[image: Microwave location]

This is the old microwave door open
[image: Door hinge]

This is the new microwave door open
[image: New door hinge]

As you can (hopefully) see, the fact the door doesn't open flush is the root of the problem.

Finally, here's a picture under the microwave next to the right hand cabinet
[image: Under microwave]

Regarding @PhilippNagel's answer below, [this is my fallback option](https://www.overstock.com/Home-Garden/Over-the-Range-Microwaves/27702/subcat.html?featuredproduct=27879217&featuredoption=48201094&ci_sku=33005449-000-000&cnc=US&cid=296708&type=&targetid=pla-1392963550059&track=pspla&gclid=CjwKCAjw2bmLBhBREiwAZ6ugo0cqSzNHCfjXtFibBCw7g7LviAVNbQRsEupNlgy9aemUUTsJUr9_lBoCqd4QAvD_BwE), although I don't like it visually or price-wise (but at this point beggars can't be choosers)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Another option is a microwave that sits "out" a little so the door and hinges are in front of the cabinet. But pictures and measurements would help a lot.

Comment: How does your old microwave avoid jamming on the wall?  Can you post a picture of that, preferably in place?  (I suppose you've removed it already, hopefully haven't discarded it yet).

Comment: What "cabinet" would you plane off?  An OTR microwave is usually not in a cabinet.  It's usually sandwiched between adjacent cabinets, and you say you don't want to change that.  If the old one was in a wood cabinet, it's not really an OTR one and there may be more options including ones with doors that open right, up, or down. (All OTR ones open left unfortunately).

Comment: Add a picture maybe we can think of something that hasn't occurred to you.

Comment: You've told us your situation, but you haven't asked a question. Are you looking for a recommendation of a brand of microwave with an inset door, or, possibly one that hinges on the other side? Are you looking for someone to validate your thought of removing the cabinet lip? This is a _Question_ and Answer board and without a _question_, we can't provide answers beyond wild guesses that may or may not be applicable to what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

What about looking for a microwave where the door is hinged on the opposite side of the ones you've tried so far? Most of them have the control panel next to the door, so that should give you plenty of room to open the door - it would open away from the wall now.

Edit: Well apparently I was too optimistic regarding the availability of a right-hinged microwave. Not even a bottom-hinged one seems available. This has been an [issue for many years](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/657711/microwave-with-hinges-on-the-right-hand-side) apparently.

However, there are a number of 24" width over the range microwaves available. One of those could be used in place of the 30" model you had, and you would just need to make some filler pieces to match your cabinets.

Alternatively, if the vent option isn't too important, you can also get over the range cabinets with an open shelf for a regular countertop microwave.

[image: picture of microwave shelf cabinet over range]
[Image source](https://thecreativecollage.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/microwave-shelf-update/)

Comment: It seems that they don't make microwaves with the hinge on the other side. They do make a few models that open like a drawer, but I don't know how handy that would be installed over a range.

Comment: @GregNickoloff I think they all (or nearly all - probably an exception somewhere) have the control panel on the right, because "right handed", and therefore door on the left and door hinge on far left because hinge next to control panel just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes, that seems to be the case. They all have the controls on the right and hinge on the left as far as I can tell.

Comment: With many refrigerators (obviously not side-by-side) it is possible to flip the door. But microwaves aren't like that because of safety interlocks. With a refrigerator, the worst that happens if your door doesn't close properly is wasted energy. With a microwave...

Comment: Hence, my original comment... they don't seem to make "left-handed" OTR microwaves.

Comment: They make microwaves with doors that open in all directions. Left, right, up, down, and out like a drawer.   The thing is, they don't make *OTR* ones like that.  OTR ones have integrated range hoods and heat protection and do not have feet. *Those* all open left.  If OP provides pictures and info requested in the Comments, we may be able to help adapt something.

Comment: Nice save, Phillipp.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I stumbled across the term "Zero Clearance Door" which led me to https://www.frigidaire.com/Owner-Center/Product-Support/LFMV1846VF
This fits perfectly up against a blocking cabinet, or a wall - if you're unlucky enough to live somewhere not up to code...

Comment: I'm not clear on the solution here. I see nothing about a zero-clearance door there on that page. Links should not be relied upon as the basis of your answer. Please revise to explain in your answer what solution you implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone. I wish I would have seen this post a year ago. Frigidaire makes a zero clearance model, FFMV1846VS soon to be model FMOS1846BS.

Answer (score 1):

I have been installing appliances for 20+ years. Both Sharp and Frigidaire make a zero clearance microwave that will work for this situation. The new, low profile, microwaves from Whirlpool also work.

Answer (score -1):

Have same issue on clients home.  Removed old micro.  Installed new one.
Well, door hits on left.  I remove and see that this has gone on awhile.
Rubbing marks on left cabinet.
Most uppers I have seen are 12 deep.
Cabinets on one wall 12 inches this wall the cabinets are 16 in
So, the answer to the problem is build out back wall couple of inches.
This should resolve door rubbing on cabinet.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, it would take a couple _feet_ in this case.